# System wget of a variable type

Tags: c, wget

So, I have several url's stored in a char pointer array called url

I want to call wget on each url, but I keep getting the following error.

```
invalid operands to binary + (have 'char *' and 'char *')
```

My program is in C

```
system("wget" + url[0]);
```

Comment: c doesn't support this concatenation i think. You should use `system(strcat("wget", url[0]))`.

Comment: codeomnitrix, your code invokes UB - `strcat` expects the destination buffer to have enough space to append the source. Could you please edit it or convert it to an answer, instead?

Answer (score 2):

In C, the `+` operator does not work on strings. To concatenate two strings and pass the result to `system()` you can do the following:

```
char buffer[ENOUGH_SPACE_TO_HOLD_CONCATENATED_RESULT];  /* Destination buffer for our command */
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "wget %s", url[0]);    /* You can also use strcat and friends for this step */
system(buffer);                                         /* Now execute it */
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, you can't concatenate two strings using the `+` operator. Use `strncat` instead:

```
NAME
       strcat, strncat - concatenate two strings

SYNOPSIS
       #include <string.h>

       char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);

       char *strncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);

DESCRIPTION
       The  strcat() function appends the src string to the dest string, over‐
       writing the null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and then adds a termi‐
       nating  null  byte.   The  strings may not overlap, and the dest string
       must have enough space for the result.

       The strncat() function is similar, except that

       *  it will use at most n characters from src; and

       *  src does not need to be null-terminated if it  contains  n  or  more
          characters.

       As  with  strcat(),  the resulting string in dest is always null-termi‐
       nated.

       If src contains n or more characters, strncat() writes  n+1  characters
       to  dest  (n  from src plus the terminating null byte).  Therefore, the
       size of dest must be at least strlen(dest)+n+1.
```

Googling "strncat" will give you plenty of examples of how it's used.